# Most Pythonic Way to Select Particular Tuple from List of Tuples

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have a list of tuples: `pairs = [(4,5),(2,6),(6,9),(8,7),(1,1)]`.

And I have a function `def m(pair): return pair[0]**2 + pair[1]**2`.

I seek to find the element of `pairs` for which `m` returns the greatest output. Specifically, I want to do this as pythonically as possible.

It is clear to me that I could do this with a loop through `pairs` and a variable to store the maximum-yielding pair seen, but that feels inelegant. I feel as if this should be done with a list comprehension. It is also clear that I could find the pair I want by declaring `temp = [m(p) for p in pairs]` and then selecting `pairs[temp.index(max(temp))]`, but I'd prefer not to create another list as long as the list of pairs -- again, this feels inelegant.

Looking for pythonic suggestions.

Comment: What do you want to happen if there are multiple elements reaching the max value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most Pythonic approach:

```
result = max(pairs, key=m)
```

Comment: Ah! Yes! This was exactly what I was thinking of when I asked! Excellent! Thank you.

Comment: I asked the question just 12 minutes ago, so I can't accept yours for another three minutes. I'll do so once I'm able to.

Answer (score -3):

Couldn't you do

> max([m(p) for p in pairs])

Comment: Nope, that returns the maximum **value**, not the **pair** yielding the maximum value. I.e. for this example, it'd return 117, rather than the desired (6,9).